# Onclick alert a string

Tags: javascript

The `onclick` in the code below is not firing the alert correctly.

Here is my code:

```js
function alert_phrase(id){
  var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
  alert(value);
}
```

```html
<div id="exp" style="background-color: white;">
  <p id="content-exp" style="color: red;">HELLO WORLD!</p>
  <input name="phrase" Placheholder="Enter text here" id="phrase" />
  <button onclick='alert_phrase(phrase)'>Alert this sentence</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You're forgetting the quotes on your parameter. Hope this helps

```js
function alert_phrase(id){
         var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
         alert(value);
 }
```

```html
<div id="exp" style="background-color: white;">
<p id="content-exp" style="color: red;">HELLO WORLD!</p>
<input name="phrase" Placheholder="Enter text here" id="phrase" />
<button onclick='alert_phrase("phrase")'>Alert this sentence</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this ...

```
<button onclick='alert_phrase("phrase")'>Alert this sentence</button>
```

Note: passing the `id` as a string to alert_phrase.

Snippet:

```js
function alert_phrase(id){
  var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
  alert(value);
}
```

```html
<div id="exp" style="background-color: white;">
  <p id="content-exp" style="color: red;">HELLO WORLD!</p>
  <input name="phrase" Placheholder="Enter text here" id="phrase" />
  <button onclick='alert_phrase("phrase")'>Alert this sentence</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad I could assist. I find it rough when I miss these myself ... more often than I'd like.